# String with whitespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a String "Magic Word". I need to use it as value in html checkbox generated by javascript.

in javascript

```
var itemValue= "Magic task";
var opt = "<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value="+ itemValue+ "/>"+itemValue+ "<br />";
alert(opt); 
$(optionDiv).append(opt);
```

In alert it is displaying the actual value but after submitting form i am getting only first word as value.It is ignoring second word.

Thanks
Ravi Kant

Comment: Nipick: You really should be using a [label element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for the text after the input.

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the value with single quotes:

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value='" + itemValue + "' />"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do not use quotes the attributes value ends at the whitespace.  Your rendered string appears as

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value=Magic Word />
```

So the parser sees

```
value=Magic
```

and an attribute `Word` with no value. You can see that with the coloring in the post above.

You need to add single quotes around the value

```
var opt = "<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value='" + itemValue + "' />"+ itemValue+ "<br />";
                                                              ^                 ^
```

Where does this fail? If you have a `'` in your string. You would need to add a replace method and swap it for `@apos;`

```
itemValue = itemValue.replace(/'/g,"@apos;");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery (as I see the usage of `$` in your code), it's better to do it with jQuery itself:

```
var itemValue= "Magic Word";
var opt = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'checkbox',
    name: 'test',
    id: 'test',
    value: itemValue
});
```

It will prevent any furthur error, for example if you have some `'` in your string:

```
var itemValue= "Magician's Word";
```

Comment: You also need to create a break tag and the textNode. ;)

Comment: @epascarello Yes, you are right, but it has another benefits, preventing errors when the string has `'` inside it, and the reading of code will be easier.

Comment: `itemValue = itemValue.replace(/'/g,"@apos;");`